# Proving an Additive Inverse

Tags: real-analysis

Working through some problems in *Understanding Analysis* I came across this relatively simple looking problem and thought I'd try it. It is stated as follows:

> Let $Z_5 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and define addition and multiplication modulo 5. In other words, compute the integer remainder when $a + b$ and $ab$ are divided by 5 and use the value for the sum and product respectively.
>
> (a) Show that given any element $z$ in $Z_5$, there exists an element $y$ such that $z + y = 0$. The element $y$ is called the *additive inverse* of $z$.

I became confused, first because in $Z_5$ $0$ does not have an additive inverse in this set (namely $5$ is missing). So I wasn't sure if I am supposed to prove that the additive inverse exists in the set or in general. If we relax that assumption showing the existence of the additive inverse goes like so (if my proof is right):

By the definition of addition in this set if $z + y = 0$ then it must be the case $0 \equiv (z + y)\mod{5}$.

Then it follows from the definition of modulus in this set: $0 - (z + y) = 5n$, that is the difference beween 0 and $z + y$ must necessarily be some integer multiple of 5.

Applying simple algebra:

$ 0 - (z + y) = 5n$

$ -z - y = 5n$

$ -z = 5n + y$

$ -z -5n = y$

and so we have shown the additive inverse of any element z in $Z_5$ as $-z -5n$.

This shows that an additive inverse exists somewhere in the real numbers. However, it doesnt show it exists in the set. Is it required that the additive inverse is in the set to solve this problem? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: An element can be its own additive inverse (since $0+0\equiv 0\pmod5$, $0$ **does** have an additive inverse in $Z_5$).

Comment: @Clayton good point, thank you. I had forgotten about that case. So then I would need to prove $-z -5n$ is in $Z_5$ for this to be valid as a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additive inverse needs to be in the set, of course. You can do it case by case in this simple example.

Comment: Ah yes, would you mind providing a more general proof for my own sake though? I'm quite interested and im sure it would be useful to me.

Comment: You were on the right track, actually. If you have $y = -z-5n$, you only need to show that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y \in \{0,\ldots, 4\}$. For $z = 0$, $n = 0$ does it. For $z \neq 0$, you can take $n = -1$. This works for all cyclic groups, not just $Z_5$.

Answer (score 0):

You begin by handling $0$ separately as @Clayton did.  Then note that any nonzero element $x$ of $Z_n$ satisfies the inequalities $0 \lt x \lt n$.  It then follows that the value $n - x$ also satisfies the same inequalities, hence is also in $Z_n$.  We finish by observing that $x + (n - x) = n = 0$ in $Z_n$.